# I created a button dynamic with the functional components, how I can get style and size from users as props

Tags: reactjs

I created a button dynamic with the functional components, I would like to get const STYLES and const SIZES from users as props, how I can get style and size from users as props?

```
import "./Button.css";
import React from "react";

const STYLES = [
  "btn btn-primary",
  "btn btn-secondary",
  "btn btn-success",
  "btn btn-danger",
  "btn btn-warning",
  "btn btn-info",
  "btn btn-light",
];

const SIZES = [
  "btn btn-primary btn-lg",
  "btn btn-secondary btn-lg",
  "btn btn-primary btn-sm",
];

const Button = ({ type, onClick, buttonStyle, buttonSize }) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
    ? buttonStyle
    : STYLES[0];
  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

  return (
    <button
      className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
      onClick={onClick}
      type={type}
    >
      Bye Now
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the `style` and `size` as states and let the user alters them with the select dropdown, and pass `styles` and `sizes` as props.

```
import "./Button.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Button = ({ type, onClick, buttonStyle, buttonSize }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={`btn ${buttonStyle} ${buttonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
      >
        {`btn ${buttonStyle} ${buttonSize}`}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const App = ({ sizes, styles }) => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState(sizes[0]);
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(styles[0]);
  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={(e) => setStyle(e.target.value)} value={style}>
        {styles.map((value) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <select onChange={(e) => setSize(e.target.value)} value={size}>
        {sizes.map((value) => (
          <option key={value} value={value}>
            {value}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <Button buttonSize={size} buttonStyle={style} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and then in somewhere else where you have `App`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App sizes={["btn btn-primary btn-lg"]} styles={["btn btn-primary"]}/>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-rubin-kj2ov?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I mean how I can remove STYLES and SIZES and pass them as a props